# Chi Squared and reduced Chi Squared = 0 with weights using lmfit

Tags: python, curve-fitting, chi-squared, lmfit

I'm using lmfit to fit Raman data. I'm using 7 Gaussian peaks and a linear background (5 of these peaks are known, and two are unknown) I've included a weights array (inverse square of the stdev). When I include the weights - the fit visually looks much better and the plotted residuals also have less structure, however, the chi-squared and reduced chi-squared values are reported as 0. I'm not sure if I'm using the weighting value correctly, or perhaps not interpreting the results correctly. I've copied my code below.
Thank you very much for any help

```
x=[ 1151.41  1155.26  1159.11  1162.96  1166.8   1170.65  1174.5   1178.35
  1182.19  1186.03  1189.88  1193.72  1197.57  1201.41  1205.25  1209.08
  1212.92  1216.77  1220.6   1224.44  1228.27  1232.11  1235.94  1239.78
  1243.61  1247.44  1251.27  1255.1   1258.94  1262.77  1266.6   1270.42
  1274.25  1278.08  1281.91  1285.73  1289.55  1293.37  1297.2   1301.02
  1304.84  1308.66  1312.48  1316.3   1320.12  1323.94  1327.75  1331.57
  1335.39  1339.2   1343.01  1346.83  1350.64  1354.45  1358.26  1362.07
  1365.88  1369.69  1373.49  1377.31  1381.11  1384.92  1388.72  1392.52
  1396.33  1400.13  1403.93  1407.73  1411.53  1415.34  1419.13  1422.93
  1426.73  1430.52  1434.32  1438.12  1441.91  1445.7   1449.49  1453.29
  1457.08  1460.87  1464.66  1468.45  1472.24  1476.03  1479.81  1483.6
  1487.38  1491.17  1494.96  1498.74]


y=[  3.34835702   3.37753701   3.46421441   3.47561446   3.52906995
   3.7430628    3.9445303    4.08069468   4.26772632   4.57141717
   4.62653264   4.95543734   5.00090221   5.03820472   4.96421951
   4.94593035   4.71712245   4.73136333   4.5449431    4.54198878
   4.68326867   4.72099151   4.79832143   4.93313301   5.23041882
   5.67948661   6.14714543   6.650372     7.289351     7.85672892
   8.52692445   9.19116051  10.00674694  10.54570038  10.87682289
  11.35534123  11.42260359  11.19421866  10.80316156  10.50632887
   9.62797798   9.1298809    8.28793321   7.73275794   7.0211812
   6.81838292   6.39480371   6.08652915   5.72148564   5.51527137
   5.21654715   5.25030395   5.28647568   5.2812212    5.36064974
   5.41940211   5.10942821   5.10866681   5.03248779   4.87465847
   4.62568491   4.60337401   4.57096411   4.56132562   4.55625841
   4.81601962   4.91783646   5.40526849   5.7393016    6.44435143
   7.27609291   8.17028904   9.53128053  10.71589492  11.74175004
  12.82955492  13.1016751   13.1616784   12.64563727  11.91554063
  10.84031597   9.74302278   8.93611092   8.01037116   7.37684127
   7.08713295   6.77556246   6.8143279    6.85773728   6.87895641
   7.02718543   7.10869694]

weights=[ 0.01244515  0.0056474   0.00926648  0.00674491  0.00553186  0.00589553
  0.00576142  0.00527653  0.00599983  0.00787368  0.00708644  0.00357355
  0.00303342  0.00916585  0.00275235  0.00328612  0.00256573  0.00370105
  0.00428572  0.00332175  0.00352448  0.00506917  0.00357058  0.00351362
  0.0040452   0.00512055  0.00217692  0.00228909  0.00237594  0.00141826
  0.00278388  0.00107677  0.00139026  0.00171414  0.0015294   0.00124306
  0.00139236  0.00160101  0.00113102  0.00125891  0.00131655  0.00172122
  0.00261752  0.00199811  0.00259736  0.00315851  0.00434901  0.00293013
  0.00338841  0.00230605  0.00272563  0.00596109  0.00420324  0.00510059
  0.00326837  0.00373911  0.00418471  0.00413105  0.00581997  0.0047461
  0.00297461  0.00713362  0.00438222  0.00304455  0.00672188  0.00444613
  0.00375129  0.00312274  0.00429026  0.00340182  0.00453605  0.00175878
  0.0021822   0.0018159   0.0014724   0.00155655  0.00093935  0.00067046
  0.00074241  0.00097113  0.0008329   0.00107734  0.00133742  0.00119752
  0.00142113  0.00174815  0.00254059  0.0033123   0.0030637   0.00280913
  0.00314901  0.00259063]

import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from lmfit.models import LinearModel
from lmfit.models import GaussianModel
import numpy as np

plotme = True


# import calibrated file
filename = 'file.csv'
data = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=",", index_col=[0], header=0)
samplename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0]

# section out the data to use
data = data.set_index('x_ref', drop=False)
fingerprint = data[data.index > 1150]
fingerprint = fingerprint[fingerprint.index < 1500]

# define the x, y, and weights
x = x
y = y
wv = weights

lin_mod1 = LinearModel(prefix='lin1_')
pars = lin_mod1.guess(y, x=x)

gauss1 = GaussianModel(prefix='one_')
pars.update(gauss1.make_params())

pars['one_center'].set(1200)
pars['one_sigma'].set(2)
pars['one_amplitude'].set(10, min=0)

gauss2 = GaussianModel(prefix='two_')
pars.update(gauss2.make_params())

pars['two_center'].set(1275)
pars['two_sigma'].set(2)
pars['two_amplitude'].set(10, min=0)

gauss3 = GaussianModel(prefix='three_')
pars.update(gauss3.make_params())

pars['three_center'].set(1450)
pars['three_sigma'].set(2)
pars['three_amplitude'].set(10, min=0)

gauss4 = GaussianModel(prefix='unknown_')
pars.update(gauss4.make_params())

pars['unknown_center'].set(1355)
pars['unknown_sigma'].set(2)
pars['unknown_amplitude'].set(10, min=0)

gauss5 = GaussianModel(prefix='unknown2_')
pars.update(gauss5.make_params())

pars['unknown2_center'].set(1510)
pars['unknown2_sigma'].set(2)
pars['unknown2_amplitude'].set(10, min=0)

gauss6 = GaussianModel(prefix='six_')
pars.update(gauss6.make_params())

pars['six_center'].set(1550)
pars['six_sigma'].set(2)
pars['six_amplitude'].set(10, min=0)

gauss7 = GaussianModel(prefix='seven_')
pars.update(gauss7.make_params())

pars['seven_center'].set(1600)
pars['seven_sigma'].set(2)
pars['seven_amplitude'].set(10, min=0)

mod = gauss1 + gauss2 + gauss3 + gauss4 + gauss5 + gauss6 + gauss7 + lin_mod1
init = mod.eval(pars, x=x)
out = mod.fit(y, pars, x=x, weights=wv)

print(out.fit_report())

if plotme:
    plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
    plt.plot(x, y, 'bo')
    # plt.plot(x, init, 'k--')
    plt.plot(x, out.best_fit, 'r-')

    comps = out.eval_components(x=x)
    plt.plot(x, comps['one_'], '--')
    plt.plot(x, comps['two_'], '--')
    plt.plot(x, comps['three_'], '--')
    plt.plot(x, comps['unknown_'], '--')
    plt.plot(x, comps['six_'], '--')
    plt.plot(x, comps['unknown2_'], '--')
    plt.plot(x, comps['seven_'], '--')
    plt.plot(x, comps['lin1_'], '--')

    plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
    plt.title('residuals')
    plt.plot(x, out.residual, '-')

    plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.95, bottom=0.10, left=0.10, right=0.95, hspace=0.50, wspace=0.35)

    plt.show()
```

output including weights:

```
[[Model]]
    (((((((Model(gaussian, prefix='one_') + Model(gaussian, prefix='two_')) + Model(gaussian, prefix='three_')) + Model(gaussian, prefix='unknown_')) + Model(gaussian, prefix='unknown2_')) + Model(gaussian, prefix='six_')) + Model(gaussian, prefix='seven_')) + Model(linear, prefix='lin1_'))
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # function evals   = 366
    # data points      = 172
    # variables        = 23
    chi-square         = 0.000
    reduced chi-square = 0.000
    Akaike info crit   = -2481.840
    Bayesian info crit = -2409.448
[[Variables]]
    lin1_intercept:       7.87347446 +/- 0.202758 (2.58%) (init= 16.00284)
    lin1_slope:          -0.00399367 +/- 0.000115 (2.88%) (init=-0.006952215)
    one_sigma:            21.2666157 +/- 1.423474 (6.69%) (init= 2)
    one_center:           1204.02129 +/- 1.132164 (0.09%) (init= 1200)
    one_amplitude:        102.715569 +/- 9.153523 (8.91%) (init= 10)
    one_fwhm:             50.0790521 +/- 3.352026 (6.69%)  == '2.3548200*one_sigma'
    one_height:           1.92685033 +/- 0.073258 (3.80%)  == '0.3989423*one_amplitude/max(1.e-15, one_sigma)'
    two_sigma:            25.7977895 +/- 0.871817 (3.38%) (init= 2)
    two_center:           1287.20816 +/- 1.068676 (0.08%) (init= 1275)
    two_amplitude:        527.208091 +/- 24.04663 (4.56%) (init= 10)
    two_fwhm:             60.7491508 +/- 2.052973 (3.38%)  == '2.3548200*two_sigma'
    two_height:           8.15285388 +/- 0.212054 (2.60%)  == '0.3989423*two_amplitude/max(1.e-15, two_sigma)'
    three_sigma:          19.5097449 +/- 0.798387 (4.09%) (init= 2)
    three_center:         1444.94305 +/- 0.757566 (0.05%) (init= 1450)
    three_amplitude:      518.683054 +/- 24.82361 (4.79%) (init= 10)
    three_fwhm:           45.9419376 +/- 1.880058 (4.09%)  == '2.3548200*three_sigma'
    three_height:         10.6062181 +/- 0.249698 (2.35%)  == '0.3989423*three_amplitude/max(1.e-15, three_sigma)'
    unknown_sigma:        33.8695907 +/- 4.913019 (14.51%) (init= 2)
    unknown_center:       1365.89866 +/- 2.572737 (0.19%) (init= 1355)
    unknown_amplitude:    224.557732 +/- 33.37427 (14.86%) (init= 10)
    unknown_fwhm:         79.7567896 +/- 11.56927 (14.51%)  == '2.3548200*unknown_sigma'
    unknown_height:       2.64501508 +/- 0.077333 (2.92%)  == '0.3989423*unknown_amplitude/max(1.e-15, unknown_sigma)'
    unknown2_sigma:       16.8566531 +/- 1.909319 (11.33%) (init= 2)
    unknown2_center:      1497.93496 +/- 1.297153 (0.09%) (init= 1510)
    unknown2_amplitude:   189.598971 +/- 27.39291 (14.45%) (init= 10)
    unknown2_fwhm:        39.6943839 +/- 4.496103 (11.33%)  == '2.3548200*unknown2_sigma'
    unknown2_height:      4.48719263 +/- 0.196189 (4.37%)  == '0.3989423*unknown2_amplitude/max(1.e-15, unknown2_sigma)'
    six_sigma:            22.0949199 +/- 2.010271 (9.10%) (init= 2)
    six_center:           1552.18018 +/- 1.324973 (0.09%) (init= 1550)
    six_amplitude:        333.936881 +/- 54.65493 (16.37%) (init= 10)
    six_fwhm:             52.0295593 +/- 4.733827 (9.10%)  == '2.3548200*six_sigma'
    six_height:           6.02951031 +/- 0.537614 (8.92%)  == '0.3989423*six_amplitude/max(1.e-15, six_sigma)'
    seven_sigma:          41.8944271 +/- 1.648292 (3.93%) (init= 2)
    seven_center:         1603.04249 +/- 4.014783 (0.25%) (init= 1600)
    seven_amplitude:      547.973799 +/- 48.61137 (8.87%) (init= 10)
    seven_fwhm:           98.6538348 +/- 3.881433 (3.93%)  == '2.3548200*seven_sigma'
    seven_height:         5.21811474 +/- 0.274354 (5.26%)  == '0.3989423*seven_amplitude/max(1.e-15, seven_sigma)'
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are <  0.100)
    C(lin1_intercept, lin1_slope)  = -0.999 
    C(seven_center, seven_amplitude)  = -0.987 
    C(unknown_sigma, unknown_amplitude)  =  0.980 
    C(unknown2_sigma, unknown2_amplitude)  =  0.971 
    C(seven_sigma, seven_center)  = -0.966 
    C(seven_sigma, seven_amplitude)  =  0.953 
    C(six_amplitude, seven_amplitude)  = -0.946 
    C(six_amplitude, seven_center)  =  0.935 
    C(one_sigma, one_amplitude)  =  0.920 
    C(six_sigma, six_amplitude)  =  0.910 
    C(two_amplitude, unknown_sigma)  = -0.900 
    C(two_amplitude, unknown_amplitude)  = -0.896 
    C(two_center, unknown_amplitude)  = -0.886 
    C(two_center, unknown_sigma)  = -0.880 
    C(six_amplitude, seven_sigma)  = -0.877 
    C(three_sigma, three_amplitude)  =  0.871 
    C(two_center, two_amplitude)  =  0.858 
    C(lin1_intercept, one_amplitude)  = -0.844 
    C(lin1_slope, one_amplitude)  =  0.839 
    C(two_sigma, two_amplitude)  =  0.826 
    C(two_sigma, unknown_center)  =  0.820 
    C(two_sigma, unknown_amplitude)  = -0.813 
    C(two_amplitude, unknown_center)  =  0.805 
    C(two_center, unknown_center)  =  0.799 
    C(six_sigma, seven_amplitude)  = -0.784 
    C(two_sigma, unknown_sigma)  = -0.764 
    C(lin1_intercept, one_sigma)  = -0.758 
    C(six_sigma, seven_center)   =  0.754 
    C(lin1_slope, one_sigma)     =  0.754 
    C(three_amplitude, unknown2_amplitude)  = -0.748 
    C(two_sigma, two_center)     =  0.737 
    C(unknown_center, unknown_amplitude)  = -0.731 
    C(three_amplitude, unknown2_sigma)  = -0.717 
    C(three_center, unknown2_amplitude)  = -0.713 
    C(three_center, unknown2_sigma)  = -0.705 
    C(three_sigma, unknown2_amplitude)  = -0.696 
    C(unknown_sigma, unknown_center)  = -0.688 
    C(unknown2_amplitude, six_sigma)  = -0.682 
    C(unknown2_amplitude, six_center)  =  0.681 
    C(unknown2_sigma, six_center)  =  0.675 
    C(six_sigma, seven_sigma)    = -0.671 
    C(three_sigma, unknown_sigma)  = -0.662 
    C(three_amplitude, unknown_sigma)  = -0.660 
    C(unknown2_sigma, six_sigma)  = -0.653 
    C(three_sigma, unknown2_sigma)  = -0.643 
    C(three_sigma, unknown_amplitude)  = -0.640 
    C(three_amplitude, unknown_amplitude)  = -0.631 
    C(three_center, three_amplitude)  =  0.621 
    C(one_center, two_sigma)     = -0.620 
    C(three_sigma, three_center)  =  0.548 
    C(two_amplitude, three_amplitude)  =  0.542 
    C(unknown2_sigma, six_amplitude)  = -0.539 
    C(unknown2_amplitude, six_amplitude)  = -0.533 
    C(two_amplitude, three_sigma)  =  0.518 
    C(two_center, three_amplitude)  =  0.517 
    C(one_amplitude, two_sigma)  = -0.497 
    C(two_center, three_sigma)   =  0.494 
    C(one_sigma, two_sigma)      = -0.484 
    C(unknown2_center, six_sigma)  = -0.483 
    C(one_center, two_amplitude)  = -0.468 
    C(one_amplitude, unknown_amplitude)  =  0.442 
    C(one_sigma, one_center)     =  0.431 
    C(one_center, one_amplitude)  =  0.422 
    C(three_sigma, unknown2_center)  =  0.416 
    C(one_center, unknown_center)  = -0.414 
    C(one_sigma, unknown_amplitude)  =  0.408 
    C(two_sigma, three_amplitude)  =  0.406 
    C(three_center, six_center)  = -0.404 
    C(three_amplitude, six_center)  = -0.398 
    C(two_sigma, three_sigma)    =  0.383 
    C(unknown2_center, six_amplitude)  = -0.374 
    C(one_center, unknown_amplitude)  =  0.364 
    C(three_amplitude, unknown2_center)  =  0.358 
    C(three_center, six_sigma)   =  0.356 
    C(one_amplitude, unknown_center)  = -0.349 
    C(three_amplitude, six_sigma)  =  0.348 
    C(three_sigma, six_center)   = -0.340 
    C(one_center, unknown_sigma)  =  0.337 
    C(unknown_sigma, unknown2_amplitude)  =  0.333 
    C(unknown_amplitude, unknown2_amplitude)  =  0.332 
    C(one_sigma, unknown_center)  = -0.329 
    C(one_amplitude, unknown_sigma)  =  0.324 
    C(unknown2_sigma, seven_amplitude)  =  0.321 
    C(unknown2_amplitude, seven_amplitude)  =  0.309 
    C(three_center, six_amplitude)  =  0.301 
    C(one_sigma, unknown_sigma)  =  0.300 
    C(unknown2_sigma, seven_center)  = -0.297 
    C(three_amplitude, six_amplitude)  =  0.296 
    C(three_sigma, six_sigma)    =  0.294 
    C(unknown_sigma, unknown2_sigma)  =  0.291 
    C(unknown_amplitude, unknown2_sigma)  =  0.288 
    C(lin1_intercept, unknown_amplitude)  = -0.286 
    C(lin1_slope, unknown_amplitude)  =  0.284 
    C(unknown2_amplitude, seven_center)  = -0.278 
    C(three_center, unknown2_center)  =  0.277 
    C(one_sigma, two_amplitude)  = -0.276 
    C(one_amplitude, two_amplitude)  = -0.275 
    C(unknown2_center, seven_amplitude)  =  0.272 
    C(unknown2_center, six_center)  =  0.265 
    C(unknown2_center, seven_center)  = -0.254 
    C(three_sigma, six_amplitude)  =  0.252 
    C(unknown2_sigma, seven_sigma)  =  0.249 
    C(two_amplitude, unknown2_amplitude)  = -0.245 
    C(two_center, unknown2_amplitude)  = -0.238 
    C(unknown_sigma, unknown2_center)  = -0.237 
    C(three_amplitude, unknown_center)  =  0.237 
    C(unknown_amplitude, unknown2_center)  = -0.228 
    C(unknown2_amplitude, seven_sigma)  =  0.225 
    C(six_sigma, six_center)     = -0.220 
    C(two_amplitude, unknown2_sigma)  = -0.215 
    C(six_center, seven_center)  =  0.212 
    C(one_amplitude, seven_sigma)  =  0.211 
    C(one_center, two_center)    = -0.208 
    C(two_center, unknown2_sigma)  = -0.207 
    C(unknown2_center, seven_sigma)  =  0.207 
    C(lin1_intercept, seven_sigma)  = -0.205 
    C(six_center, seven_sigma)   = -0.205 
    C(six_center, seven_amplitude)  = -0.205 
    C(one_amplitude, two_center)  = -0.201 
    C(one_amplitude, seven_amplitude)  =  0.190 
    C(lin1_intercept, two_sigma)  =  0.189 
    C(one_sigma, seven_sigma)    =  0.188 
    C(lin1_slope, two_sigma)     = -0.188 
    C(two_sigma, unknown2_amplitude)  = -0.187 
    C(lin1_slope, seven_sigma)   =  0.186 
    C(lin1_intercept, seven_amplitude)  = -0.185 
    C(two_amplitude, unknown2_center)  =  0.183 
    C(two_center, unknown2_center)  =  0.173 
    C(one_center, three_amplitude)  = -0.173 
    C(one_sigma, seven_amplitude)  =  0.170 
    C(three_center, seven_amplitude)  = -0.170 
    C(lin1_slope, seven_amplitude)  =  0.169 
    C(one_sigma, two_center)     = -0.166 
    C(three_amplitude, seven_amplitude)  = -0.166 
    C(lin1_intercept, unknown_sigma)  = -0.164 
    C(lin1_slope, unknown_sigma)  =  0.163 
    C(three_sigma, unknown_center)  =  0.162 
    C(two_sigma, unknown2_sigma)  = -0.161 
    C(three_center, seven_center)  =  0.160 
    C(one_center, three_sigma)   = -0.157 
    C(three_amplitude, seven_center)  =  0.156 
    C(lin1_intercept, unknown_center)  =  0.146 
    C(lin1_slope, unknown_center)  = -0.146 
    C(one_amplitude, seven_center)  = -0.145 
    C(three_sigma, seven_amplitude)  = -0.145 
    C(unknown_amplitude, six_sigma)  = -0.141 
    C(unknown_amplitude, six_amplitude)  = -0.137 
    C(unknown_sigma, six_center)  =  0.136 
    C(lin1_intercept, seven_center)  =  0.135 
    C(three_center, unknown_center)  = -0.135 
    C(three_sigma, seven_center)  =  0.134 
    C(unknown_sigma, six_sigma)  = -0.133 
    C(three_center, seven_sigma)  = -0.132 
    C(two_sigma, unknown2_center)  =  0.132 
    C(three_amplitude, seven_sigma)  = -0.130 
    C(one_sigma, seven_center)   = -0.130 
    C(unknown_amplitude, six_center)  =  0.126 
    C(one_amplitude, three_sigma)  = -0.123 
    C(one_amplitude, six_amplitude)  = -0.122 
    C(unknown_sigma, six_amplitude)  = -0.122 
    C(lin1_slope, seven_center)  = -0.121 
    C(unknown_amplitude, seven_amplitude)  =  0.118 
    C(three_sigma, seven_sigma)  = -0.116 
    C(unknown_amplitude, seven_sigma)  =  0.114 
    C(one_sigma, three_sigma)    = -0.113 
    C(unknown2_center, unknown2_amplitude)  =  0.111 
    C(one_sigma, six_amplitude)  = -0.109 
    C(unknown2_sigma, unknown2_center)  =  0.109 
    C(one_amplitude, unknown2_amplitude)  =  0.107 
    C(two_amplitude, six_center)  = -0.107 
    C(lin1_intercept, six_amplitude)  =  0.105 
    C(lin1_intercept, two_center)  =  0.101
```

[image: components and residuals stacked with weights included in fit]

Answer (score 2):

The report of the chi-square statistic is limited to 3 digits in the version you are using. I believe this was fixed in the most recent release (0.9.9), and is definitely fixed in the latest development version.  You can also print out the values with more precision yourself:

```
print("chi-square = %14.8g, reduced chi-square = %14.8g" % (out.chisqr, out.redchi))
```

But also: I think using weights of "inverse square of the stdev" may not be what you want. For clarity, the weights are a multiplicative factor applied to (data-model), and then chi-square would be "Sum [(data-model)*weights]**2".   So I think using "weight = 1./(stddev of the data)" (that is, not squared) is the most common approach for data that is expected to be normally distributed, and your Raman data probably is, at least in the sense of not having a signal dominated by counting small numbers (where Poission statistics would be preferred).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information regarding the use of  stddev compared to the variance as a weighting factor. I had chosen to use the inverse square after the default in Sigma Plot's Peak Fit: "When each data pair consists of an average of Y observations at a given x, you may wish to set that pair’s weight value to the inverse square of the standard deviation." I'm not sure why I would want to use the inverse variance in one case in the inverse standard deviation in other. Thank you.

Comment: I think this may be related to units of measurement, as standard deviation has no units and variance does have units. Describing weights for the same experiment made using units of kilometers and millimeters will have the same standard deviation values with very different variance values (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Units_of_measurement)

Comment: @JamesPhillips That's an excellent point.  Dimensional analysis is a simple, powerful (and easily overlooked!) problem solving tool.  If `data` and `model` have some dimension, `weights` should have 1/dimension.

Comment: Additionally, discussing weights in terms of standard deviations makes them equally understood in many different experimental contexts precisely *because* the weights would then be dimensionless.